# Lambda expression - OR Operator evaluating both sides

Tags: c#, lambda

I've got the following code which matches an exact culture, or a wildcard version of the culture.

Using a culture of 'en-TH' the string returned should be 'en-**' as this has been matched by a wildcard. A culture of 'en-US' will return 'en-US' and a culture of 'ar-AK' will return null.

However, with the code below, a culture of 'en-US' returns two strings:

```
"en-US"
"en-**"
```

I am wondering if this is because the OR operator is NOT doing "short-circuit" evaluation in this context?  I.E. I don't want 'en-**' to be returned in this instance

```
string cultureToMatch = "en-TH";
IEnumerable<string> cultures = new string[] { "en-US", "en-**", "fr-**", "en-KH", "ar-AR" };

for (int i = 0; i < cultureToMatch.Length; i++)
{
    char searchChar = cultureToMatch[i];
    cultures = cultures.Where(w => w.IndexOf(searchChar, i, 1) >= 0 ||
                                   w.IndexOf('*', i, 1) >= 0)
                                    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with short-circuit evaluation. Your code is returning two strings because that's what you've written it to do. Nothing in that snippet says that `cultures` must have less than 2 values at the end.

Comment: I'll refine further then, thanks... unless someone wants to suggest a quick refinement for the win?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead.  It will try to filter on the actual character first and only if there are no matches will it try to filter using the wildcard.

```
string cultureToMatch = "en-US";
IEnumerable<string> cultures = new string[] { "en-US", "en-**", "fr-**", "en-KH", "ar-AR" };

for (int i = 0; i < cultureToMatch.Length; i++)
{
    char searchChar = cultureToMatch[i];
    var tempFilter = cultures.Where(w => w.IndexOf(searchChar, i, 1) >= 0);
    if (!tempFilter.Any())
        tempFilter = cultures.Where(w => w.IndexOf('*', i, 1) >= 0);
    cultures = tempFilter.ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's because the condition is evaluated separately for each item.

The string `en-US` matches the first part of the condition, and the string `en-**` matches the second part of the condition. The fact that the first part of the condition is true for one item doesn't prevent the second part of the condition to be evaluated for a different item.

If you want to search for the most relevant match, you either have to make two runs through the data, or sort the result on relevance and get the first match.